# Sum up entries from json and save it in a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, json, jq

I have the below json file

```
[
    {
        "n_id": 1,
        "n_key": "sdfvnifughsdfvnsdfvnsd",
        "entries": 7
    },
    {
        "n_id": 2,
        "n_key": "amfgjbongmikjmjegieojgem",
        "entries": 8
    },
    {
        "n_id": 3,
        "n_key": "fdsggjhndsjfsjinfjghbdpojgd",
        "entries": 10
    }
]
```

How can I sum up all the entries in the above json file and save it in a variable **JSON_SUM** ??

I have zero knowledge in working with a json file, can someone please help me. I want to use this in a bash script

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
$ json_sum=$(jq '[ .[] | .entries ] | add' file.json)
$ echo $json_sum
25
```

Comment: `[ .[] | .entries ]` can also be written as `map(.entries)`